# React Native: Typescript - data possibly undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've got a some data being fetched using RTK Query. I load this data (array of objects)  in a screen and then slice some portion of it.

It's more of a typescript question but I'll post the apiSlice:

```
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

export const blogpostsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'blogpostsApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3500' }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getBlogPosts: builder.query<Post[], void>({
      query: () => '/todos',
      transformResponse: (res: Post[], meta) => res.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id),
    }),
  }),
});
```

The relevant excerpts from the screen:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useGetBlogPostsQuery();
const latestData = data?.slice(0, 10);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData.length > 0 && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData[0].id === 'something' && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
```

As you can see, I've added the optional chaining operator to `data?.slice...` (as this is a recommended solution for that on SO, from what I have seen. But then typescript also underlines all the instances of `latestData.length` and `latestData[0].id`.

Now I know I could silence the typescript error by adding the optional chaining operator to all those instances as well but I'm wondering it that's really the best way of doing it for 2 reasons:

1. Adding it to all the instances will unnecessarily increase the compiled code length
2. The way I use `latestData` above in the two effects is in conditional statements to check if it exists/is defined so it is perfectly OK for it to be undefined.

So I guess my question is what would be the correct way to solve this error. Isn't adding the optional chaining operator just a quick and dirty hack to silence the error especially if it appears in conditional statements? I know I could also suppress the error by asking Webstorm to ignore it (as per the error screenshot below)
The error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely normal behaviour.

The optional chaining operator is not a Typescript thing, it's Javascript and it works like that:

`myVar?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3`

If `myVar` is `undefined` (or `null`), the rest of the code won't be evaluated and the whole expression will return `undefined`.

Then, if `myVar` is not `undefined` (or `null`), then the code will try to access the `prop1` property of `myVar`.

Since there is a `?` after `prop1`, it will repeat the same process until it finds `undefined`/`null` or after it reaches the end of the chain without finding any `undefined`/`null`.

It seems like you are confusing the Javascript `?` operator with the Typescript `!` non-null assertion.

If you only want to tell the compiler that you are confident about a variable being "non-null" (that also means non `undefined`), you can use the `!` operator instead.

Like so:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useGetBlogPostsQuery();
const latestData = data!.slice(0, 10); // change this line here
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData.length > 0 && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData[0].id > 0 && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
```

However, you should really check manually if `data` is not `undefined` or `null` before using it. And that would even release you from having to use any assertion operator !

Like that:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useGetBlogPostsQuery();
if (!data){
  // do something to handle the problem
}
const latestData = data.slice(0, 10);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData.length > 0 && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && latestData[0].id > 0 && some_other_condition) {
    ... some code
    }
}, [latestData]);
```